# pivot in pandas: how to edit the columns and rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

i face a problem with pivot in pandas ,
the total_profit and numberofgoodsold columns are located above company row.
i need the company row to be at the top.

in each company the total_profit and the goodsold columns should came under.

this is my code:

```
data = {'company': ['AMC', 'ER','CRR' , 'TYU'], 'Reg-ID': ['1222','2334','3444', '4566'], 'Total_provit': ['123300','12233', '3444444', '412222'], 'numberofgoodsold':['44','23','67','34']}

d = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

```
d.pivot(index = 'Reg-ID', columns = 'company')
```

Comment: Hi and welcome Pythona. Please don't post screenshots. Use the codeblock and provide some reproducible data.

Comment: i deleted the link. thank you

Comment: Can you explain why the result in your screenshot is not what you want? It looks like the expected result...

Comment: no, what i need is company sort at the top, then all columns came under the company. under each company i want to see the total_profit and numberofgoodsold.

Comment: Thanks Pythona, please read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples . This makes it way easier to help . If you post a reproducible dataset the chance you're getting an answer is much bigger.

Comment: Thanks for the update Pythona. Tried to answer your question below. But besides that I'd suggest to read [How to I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). It really helped me at beginning here. Before it was sometimes quite frustrating, but only because I didn't know some basic rules :-) PS: I upvoted your question now, because I think that a negative vote is no longer appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update,** ok then I think this is what you need:

```
data = {'company': ['AMC', 'ER','CRR' , 'TYU'], 'Reg-ID': ['1222','2334','3444', '4566'], 'Total_provit': ['123300','12233', '3444444', '412222'], 'numberofgoodsold':['44','23','67','34']}

d = pd.DataFrame(data)

d2 = d.pivot(index = 'Reg-ID', columns = 'company')

d2.columns = d2.columns.swaplevel(0, 1)
d2.sort_index(axis=1, level=0, inplace=True)

d2
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you. It is what I want, but I would like Order to be something this: company1 then column1 and colmun2, then again company2 then column1 and column2.

Comment: See update, I think this is what you wanted? Pls check and give feedback.

Comment: this is exactly what i needed. Thank you...!!